# Using PowerBI to show sharepoint online usage

Tags: auditing, powerbi

I would like to provide a usage /audit reporting for SharePoint Online
I have enabled Audit logs and i can view the excelsheet report.
What im not sure about is do i have to go and create the report everytime i need it??

Can i use powerbi to read the excel file on the fly

Thanks in Advance

Comment: powerbi.microsoft.com  you will find tutorial here